# I fail to use pycharm to install matplotlib package(Windows 10, python3.7)

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

### I try to use pycharm to install "matplotlib" with "file -> settings -> project interpreter -> add -> matplotlib -> install", but it prompt:

```
Collecting matplotlib

Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/ed/46b835da53b7ed05bd4c6cae293f13ec26e877d2e490a53a709915a9dcb7/matplotlib-2.2.2.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [2.2.2]
                python: yes [3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018,
                        04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]]
              platform: yes [win32]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [version 1.14.5]
      install_requires: yes [handled by setuptools]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype
                        (freetype2\ft2build.h) could not be found.  You may
                        need to install the development package.]
                   png: no  [The C/C++ header for png (png.h) could not be
                        found.  You may need to install the development
                        package.]
                 qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'libqhull' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]

OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
           sample_data: yes [installing]
              toolkits: yes [installing]
                 tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
        toolkits_tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]

OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                qt5agg: no  [PySide2 not found; PyQt5 not found]
                qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
               gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
             gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                 tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                        Tk]
                 wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                   gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                   agg: yes [installing]
                 cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
             windowing: yes [installing]

OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                dvipng: yes [version 1.12]
           ghostscript: yes [version 9.05]
                 latex: yes [version MiKTeX 2.9]
               pdftops: no

OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                  dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

============================================================================
                        * The following required packages can not be built:
                        * freetype, png
                        * Please check http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packa
                        * ges/freetype.htm for instructions to install
                        * freetype
                        * Please check http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packa
                        * ges/libpng.htm for instructions to install png

----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\matplotlib\"
```

I think it fail to install freetype and png.  I search for some information, but the way to Anaconda or Miniconda both support python3.6 or python2.7, so I don't know how to solve this problem.

Thank you for your help！

yuxq

Comment: have you tried going to the doc site and install the packages with their tool ? Error gives you 2 url : http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/freetype.htm and http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/ges/libpng.htm

Comment: This tool has its flaws unfortunately. From my experience, this is not the tool of choice for downloading libraries, it sometimes work, sometimes not, and it is never clear why.
Can you try in the terminal (within Pycharm) to type `conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib`. This is what is officially recommended here: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/matplotlib

Comment: all methods are OK!, thank you for your help.